# Project both webform mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a project developed with WebForms while
I would like to continue the rest of developement with MVC.  How i do that ??

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible, 
you will required to do changes in web.config for handling ensuring both MVC & webforms works. thats one time setup you needs to complete.

there are many articles available online.
for eg. check https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38778/ASP-NET-WebForms-and-ASP-NET-MVC-in-Harmony

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I Agree, but solution is quite lengthy so better to reuse existing content from other communities.

Comment: I haven't downvoted. I don't downvote when I'm moderating.

Comment: For further information see [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351896/why-does-stack-overflow-auto-downvote)